# Installing Skype on Ubuntu 16.04 broken apt package installer

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, skype

I'm running Ubuntu server 16.04 64bit and just tried to install skype with the following commands:

```
**Add Skype repo**
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
**Add i386 architecture**
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
**Update and install**
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

It exited with failure. Unmet package dependencies.

I have since tried,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I still got the same error, so then i tried removing the repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then I tried doing an apt-get update again and sudo apt-get -f install still with the same error. I'm not sure where to turn now, can anyone help with this? See the final command set and results below:-

```
attilio@atf-gz-office-1:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
attilio@atf-gz-office-1:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done
attilio@atf-gz-office-1:~$ sudo apt-get clean
attilio@atf-gz-office-1:~$ sudo apt-get -f installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-63
  linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-67
  linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libpulse0:i386
Suggested packages:
  pulseaudio:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libpulse0:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 101 not upgraded.
136 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,033 kB of archives.
After this operation, 123 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2 [252 kB]
Get:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [4,781 kB]
Fetched 5,033 kB in 23s (213 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 392281 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpulse0_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse0:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpulse0_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/pulse/client.conf', which is different from other instances of package libpulse0:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/drirc', which is different from other instances of package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpulse0_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.2_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried a manual install and got this:

```
attilio@atf-gz-office-1:/home$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
dpkg: considering removing skype-bin:i386 in favour of skype:i386 ...
dpkg: skype-bin:i386 is not properly installed; ignoring any dependencies on it
dpkg: yes, will remove skype-bin:i386 in favour of skype:i386
(Reading database ... 392281 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype:i386 (4.3.0.37-1) over (4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-dbus:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-xml:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1); however:
  Package libstdc++6:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libx11-6; however:
  Package libx11-6:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on libxext6; however:
  Package libxext6:i386 is not configured yet.
 skype:i386 depends on 
dpkg: error processing package skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
```

**EDIT:**
I ran the commands again on a 1-for-1 copy of the server (before the update) and it showed this error just before it died:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3_8.39-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1_i386.deb  Connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.9.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2_i386.deb  Connection timed out

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you tried to install manually the .deb package from skype download page?

Comment: this? I can't see anything...

Comment: Maybe you can update the question with the output of  whatever happened when you tried to install manually the deb from skype

Comment: added to the question. cheers

Comment: I think it's relates to the pulseaudio...

Comment: yeah I think so too, but how can i upgrade just that package? should I download it manually?

Comment: should i revert by trying sudo dpkg --force-all -P skype  ?

Comment: Looks like several errors, all caused by software from non-Ubuntu-sources that is incompatible with Skype. You get to decide which one you want - you can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should uninstall pulse audio and then try to install again Skype without any package of pulseaudio installed into the system.

Comment: ok thanks. whats the recommended way to uninstall pulseaudio this now my apt-get is broken? would it be dpkg --force-all -P pulseaudio

Comment: Try sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio and then if you don't have any errors related to the pulse audio removal try again to install skype